# SOQL Query for first Contacts

Tags: soql, account, contact

I have a list of accounts and want to get first contact of each account, like:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = xxx LIMIT 1
```

I can get all contacts with:

```
List<Account> al = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 100];
List<Contact> cl = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :al];
```

In my case list of accounts doesn't come from query, they are selected by user.
Is there a way to get only first contact of each account in SOQL query without looping over result?

Comment: What do you mean by "first"? Please **[edit]** your question to be more specific.

Comment: As I wrote: the first contact returned by SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = xxx LIMIT 1, just first one stored for related account.

Comment: If you don't *explicitly* order your Contacts, you shouldn't rely on them being ordered deterministically or in any specific order when they're selected (even though in practice they may be).

Answer (score 4):

You'd can use a sub-query for this:

```
Account[] al = [SELECT 
  (SELECT Name FROM Contacts ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) 
   FROM Account WHERE Id = :selectedAccounts];
```

Each Account record in al will have at most one selected contact.

Answer (score 0):

If you want first created contact for that Account you can change your SOQL like this

```
[SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :al order by createdDate desc limit 1];
```